# Simple JS regex replace.

Tags: javascript, regex

I am struggling trying to create a really simple RegExp. (probably lacking some hours of sleep).

I just have has an input this string : /users/10/contracts/1
My regex is this one : /users/(\w+)/contracts/(\w+)/

I want to replace all matches with this kind of string : /users/{variable1}/contracts/{variable2}

Here is my complete source code :

```
var customRegex = "/users/(\\w+)/contracts/(\\w+)";
  var i =0;
  var finalUrl = "/users/1234/contracts/5678".replace(new RegExp(customRegex, 'gi'), function myFunction(x, y){
    return "{variable" + i + "}"; 
  });

  console.log(finalUrl);
```

Could you please help me?

I wish you a nice day and thank you for your help.

Comment: Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) with a counter. [`var finalUrl = "/users/1234/contracts/5678";

var i = 1;
finalUrl = finalUrl.replace(/\d+/g, function () {
    return "{variable" + i++ + "}";
});

console.log(finalUrl);`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/fvyo6ogz/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replace-function is only called once for the whole replacement.
You are using 2 matchers so you also get 2 matches as parameters in the callback-function.

```
var customRegex = "/users/(\\w+)/contracts/(\\w+)";
var finalUrl = "/users/1234/contracts/5678".replace(new RegExp(customRegex, 'gi'), function myFunction(wholeString, p1, p2){
    return wholeString.replace(p1, "{variable1}").replace(p2, "{variable2}"); 
});
console.log(finalUrl);
```

Comment: You don't need `i` flag because `\w`  matches both uppercase and lowercase alphabets

Comment: Thank you Jens. It was exactly what i wanted :)

Comment: @Tushar indeed, just copied it from his question. Maybe he simplified his question and is using a more complex pattern but for this one you are completly right, good hint.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match the numbers only, it should do the work.

```js
var finalUrl = "/users/1234/contracts/5678";

finalUrl.match(/\d+/g).forEach(function(v, i) { 
  finalUrl = finalUrl.replace(v, "{variable" + (i + 1) + "}"); 
});

document.write(finalUrl);
```

Comment: You don't need `i` flag for numbers. Never heard of `(upp|low)erCase` numbers. :P